# want to create uploading and receiving web for 3d printing(stl format)

Tags: database, file-upload, stl, format, web-development-server

I am new to web development and I want to create a website that allows uploading and receiving files(STL) format for 3d printing. I know HTML and CSS.

I want to know the roadmap for creating that website. It can be very simple but it must work. Is my project involves the backend?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.